# which ng-click takes precedence in a table?

Tags: angularjs

Say I have a table and ng-click is defined both at the row level and the individual cell level:

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="..."  ng-click="ctrl.action1()" >
    <td>
      <a class="..." ng-click="ctrl.action2()"><i class="..."></i></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Which one will be executed first, action1 or action2? Is the order guaranteed? Also parallel or sequential?

Comment: you should check http://stackoverflow.com/a/4616720/594438

Comment: They will all trigger, starting with action2. You can stopPropagation though to prevent action1 from happening. But action2 will always happen.

Comment: Thanks Romulo and Notidart. I have a follow-up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027344/is-there-a-way-to-force-ng-click-to-execute-first-on-parent-then-on-child