# is there a way to force ng-click to execute first on parent, then on child

Tags: angularjs

This is a follow-up question to [which ng-click takes precedence in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33026912/which-ng-click-takes-precedence-in-a-table?noredirect=1#comment53876193_33026912)

Basically, I'd like to ensure, that whenever the cell is clicked, action1 will be executed first, completed, followed by action2. Is there a way to enforce that?

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="..."  ng-click="ctrl.action1()" >
    <td>
      <a class="..." ng-click="ctrl.action2()"><i class="..."></i></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: does `action1` involve asynchronous operations?

Comment: Potentially, yes. It's essentially to ensure the object is refreshed and it may trigger a server call.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I can think of, don't let the event bubble and call `action1` from inside `action2`

```
<a class="..." ng-click="ctrl.action2($event)"><i class="..."></i></a>
```

Controller

```
$scope.action2 = function(evt){
     evt.stopPropagation();
     $scope.action1();
     // other action2 code
}
```

Assumes no asynchronous operations in `action1()` and you probably need to pass in other arguments for data item on that row

There is an alternative also to get rid of `action2` in html, pass the event into action one and check the target of event

Comment: There are potentially asynchronous operations in action1.

Comment: then you would need to wrap the remainder of action1 code in callback from the async operation. Or switch the name of existing `action2` and use this as a new one and call the old one in the callback